# A question about the word repellent

Tags: hyphens

which one is correct? Rub some of this mosquito repellent on your legs or Rub some of this mosquito-repellent on your legs. I think the first one is correct. However, I have seen the second one in Oxford Advanced.

Comment: The first one is correct. I am not sure why anyone would use the second one.

Comment: @mdewey As I said I found it in an old version of Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary